# Java EE 8 tutorial - Maven archetype does not exist

Tags: java, maven, glassfish, jax-rs, maven-archetype

I'm trying to do this [tutorial](https://javaee.github.io/tutorial/jaxrs003.html#GIQAA) from [Java EE 8 tutorial](https://javaee.github.io/tutorial/toc.html).

I'm following the [instructions](https://javaee.github.io/tutorial/usingexamples007.html#CHDJGCCA) on how to install tutorial archetypes, which I've downloaded from this [repository](https://github.com/javaee/tutorial-examples).

Error message printed in the bottom.

Is this related to the fact that the repository is archived, and the tutorials are outdated, or am I doing something wrong?

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Maven Stub Project (No POM) 1
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] >>> maven-archetype-plugin:3.1.0:generate (default-cli) > generate-sources @ standalone-pom >>>
[INFO] 
[INFO] <<< maven-archetype-plugin:3.1.0:generate (default-cli) < generate-sources @ standalone-pom <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-archetype-plugin:3.1.0:generate (default-cli) @ standalone-pom ---
[INFO] Generating project in Batch mode
[WARNING] Archetype not found in any catalog. Falling back to central repository.
[WARNING] Add a repository with id 'archetype' in your settings.xml if archetype's repository is elsewhere.
[WARNING] The POM for org.glassfish.javaeetutorial:jaxrs-service-archetype:jar:4.0.0 is missing, no dependency information available
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 4.765 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-06-10T20:16:02+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 15M/195M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:3.1.0:generate (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: The desired archetype does not exist (org.glassfish.javaeetutorial:jaxrs-service-archetype:4.0.0) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

Comment: It just saying that cannot find `jaxrs-service-archetype` in maven repository. I tried https://mvnrepository.com/search?q=jaxrs-service-archetype  . no luck. Maybe too old.

Comment: It seems to be downloaded from the repository though, its located right in the archetypes folder: https://github.com/javaee/tutorial-examples/tree/master/archetypes

Comment: oh.. it is a private one. If so, you need download and install locally, you should be fine.

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I've done, as described in my post, which produces the error...

Comment: I am sorry. But I am pretty sure your installation failed. You can check if it eixists in your `.m2` folder